# SceneKit error loading skinned character

Tags: swift, scenekit, collada

Whenever I try to load a scene with a skinned character I get an error:

```
SceneKit: error, Library Deserialization: cannot finalize the deserialization of <C3DSkin ...>
```

The code generating the error:

```
let heroScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/hero.scn")!
```

This includes any .dae character file I download from the internet, as well as the hero character from Apple's WWDC slideshow.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug with Xcode 8. I filed a bug report with Apple which is now marked as a duplicate of another "open" report. So I hope Apple's going to fix this with the next Xcode update.

EDIT: This bug has been fixed in Xcode 8.2 beta.